# Parse time from string that contains weekname and time

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to parse only time ignoring weekday from the string with the following format: "Monday 5AM"

Here is my code:

```
String dateTxt = "Monday 5AM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha");
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(dateTxt, formatter);
```

It throws an exception:
`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Saturday 1AM' could not be parsed`

How to parse only time from that string?

Comment: Even if you don't *care* about the weekday, you'll need to tell the parser to expect the weekday to be present in the input, or it will not know what to do with the text. In other words: the format string describes the text that you **expect to be present** and not the *data that you care about*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the format to

```
"EEEE ha"
```

I would also recommend to set the Locale so you have the right language and that it supports AM/PM

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE ha", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

---

I see the question has been edited now, if you only want the time you can extract or format that from the parse `LocalTime` object

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(dateTxt, formatter);
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(lt);
System.out.println(lt.format(formatter2));
```

> 05:00
> 5 AM

Comment: As day is being ignored(optional) this pattern could be used `[EEEE] ha`. `[` and `]` indicates optional section.

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the issue here is it? Your format is usable when the input string may _or_ may not include the weekday.

Comment: @onkarruikar I didn't know [ ]  means optional. Cheers buddy.

Answer (score 5):

If we want to ignore the day then we can use following patterns:
`[` optional section start
`]` optional section end

This has different behavior while parsing and formatting. Note: the same pattern has been used for parsing and formatting in following code.

```
    String dateTxt = "Monday 5AM";
    //for parsing day of week is ignored
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[EEEE ]ha", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(dateTxt, formatter);
    System.out.println(lt + " - parsed local time ");
    
    //in case of formatting if data is not available 
    //then the field won't be in output
    System.out.println(lt.format(formatter) + " -local time with optnal day in format.");
    
    //the day is available so it will be there in output
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(ldt.format(formatter) + " -local date time with optnal day in format");
```

Output:

```
05:00 - parsed local time 
5AM -local time with optnal day in format.
Saturday 2PM -local date time with optnal day in format
```

For formatting if the data is not available then that won't be in output.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant with your comment to my answer, the same formatter can be reused for output as well. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the time, why not just extract that part from `dateTxt` and parse that part only.

```java
String dateTxt = "Monday 5AM";
DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
DateTimeFormatter fmtr = dtfb.appendValue(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM)
                             .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.SHORT)
                             .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
String timeTxt = dateTxt.split(" ")[1];
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(timeTxt, fmtr));
```

Comment: Yep, another solution would be to extract time from the string and parse it, but your code looks too complicated and difficult to read. I could use regex to extract time, it'll be one line code.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev the point of the answer is to demonstrate using class `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` as an alternative to directly using class `DateTimeFormatter`. Although possibly overkill, it may benefit future visitors to this Q&A.

Comment: Splitting date strings won't be locale sensitive. :(

Comment: I would only recommend this way if one wanted *not* to validate whether the day of week is a valid day of week. Meaning that for most purposes the validation would be a plus rather than something to avoid.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev `dateTxt.split(" ")[1]` is one line too, and IMHO more straightforward to read than the simplest regular expression.